# Could we change the badges to a saturn like planet?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On Bio SE the badges look like genes. Could Astronomy SE change the badges to a ringed planet like Saturn?

Comment: Sites get special designs when they "graduate". I'll explain more on Monday. You can also look up graduation on Meta SE for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Building site design is a large effort, so this effort is limited to "graduated" sites. Further explanation is below.

---

What is graduation? From [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites):

> Graduation is a hard concept to pin down quantitatively, but we basically expect that a graduated site should be able to continue growing and governing itself indefinitely without any outside help unless something truly catastrophic happens.

User summary of graduation:

> [T]here are six effects of graduation:
>
> - **Site Design:** [...]
> - **Moderator Elections:** [...]
> - **Community Ads:** [...]
> - **Reputation Levels:** [...]
> - **Full migration target:** [...]
> - **Being listed in the footer:** [...]

From [What are the design elements that could be changed upon graduation of a site? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107246/what-are-the-design-elements-that-could-be-changed-upon-graduation-of-a-site):

> Each graduating site gets its own unique design theme created by Stack Exchange's professional in-house design team (currently Jin), working with other designers as needed.
>
> So far, every site's theme has included
>
> - a custom logo and favicon
> - custom decorative graphics (or intentional lack thereof)
> - a consistent color scheme
>
> Most sites have also received
>
> - unique fonts consistent with the site theme
> - decorative boxes and borders consistent with the site theme
> - themed badge shapes/sizes/colors (color referring to background color, not bronze/silver/gold)
> - themed tag shapes/sizes/colors
> - unique upvote/downvote/favorite button images
>
> Some sites have other changes that have to do with their topics. Photography's top bar is organized differently to make room for a "featured photo." Unix and Linux has slashes prepended to the text of its header buttons to give the feel that those link to "subdirectories" of the site. And Apple's `<kbd>` markup looks like an Apple keyboard's key.

From [When Will My Site Graduate? - Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/):

> ## How long can a site stay in beta?
>
> The simple answer is, it takes as long as it takes. We'll wait. If a site needs more activity, go out and evangelize it. As long as your site shows steady progress and continues to make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions, it will march on. We don't want to kill a site because it hasn't reached full status in 90 days. Nor do we want to set a hard 90-day limit and launch a site too soon.
>
> There's more to the health of a Stack Exchange site than having a lot of questions and answers. There's an economy to the site with reputation as its currency, and voting drives that economy. A site absolutely needs on-going, sustained voting to build a class of leaders that help run and govern the site. Without leadership, there can be no community.
>
> So from this point forward, the graduation date of a site will depend heavily on having enough users with sufficient reputation to properly lead and govern the site. It's much more important to graduate a site when it has become self-sustaining, and has established a healthy community of avid users, closers, and editors -- rather than imposing an arbitrary 90-day limit.
>
> Thus, the order of launch will favor those beta sites which have achieved the most "excellent" ratings on our Area 51 stats panel. For everyone else -- keep going!

Also, now, graduation does not necessarily mean that we will receive a design right away. From [Feedback Requested: Design-Independent Graduation - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation):

> ### The Community Team announces that a site is cleared for graduation. Without delay...
>
> - the beta label is removed
> - elections are held
> - migration paths are set up
> - community ads are run
> - a link to the site is added to the footer
>
> ### ...Then, as it becomes available
>
> - the site gets their custom design.
> - privilege thresholds are increased to graduated site levels

Comment: Nice answer. It might be worth mentioning something about [design-independent graduation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260754/274942). In the case of some sites, there's been quite a gap. On Worldbuilding, six months and one day elapsed between the graduation announcement and the launch of the design.